# xparse optional arguments lead to error in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, xparse

I am trying to create a few simple macros for B-Trees and one of these macros is supposed to create a multipart node tikz based on the number of arguments it gets. Therefore I used the `g` argument specifier from xparse though tikz always shows the following error:

```
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. ;
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. ;
Undefined control sequence. ;
```

The macro works flawlessly when replacing the `g`s with `m`s though then it becomes impossible to differentiate between a multipart node with e.g. 4 segments two of which are empty and an 2 segment node which are all filled.

A kinda minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes.multipart}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{m g}{
  {#1 \IfValueT{#2}{B}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand\leaf{m m}{
  node[leaf]{#1 \nodepart{two} #2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand\leafOptional{m g}{
  node[leaf]{#1 \IfValueT{#2}{\nodepart{two} #2}}
}


\tikzset{
  btree/.style={
    nodes={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal=true,draw},
    leaf/.style={
      rectangle split allocate boxes=2,
      rectangle split parts=2,
      rectangle split part fill=white}
  },
}

\begin{document}
\test{a}\\ % this works
\test{a}{something}\\ % as does this
\begin{tikzpicture}[btree]
\node (root) {test}
  child {\leaf{5}{}}
  child {\leafOptional{5}} % however this fails
  child {\leafOptional{5}{}} % and so does this
  child {node[leaf]{1}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I already found this question [TikZ path doesn't work with xparse generated macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79646/tikz-path-doesnt-work-with-xparse-generated-macro) which seems to be a similar problem though I am unable to use `\DeclareDocumentCommand` as it does not allow one to use the `g`/`G` argument specifier

#### Addedum

Following @PhelypeOleinik's comment I changed the code to use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` and the argument specifier `o o o m` however when passing more than one optional argument this leads to tikz not determining the correct node bounding box and tikz draws the edge into the actual node shape.

[image: tikz drawing into the multipart node]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes.multipart}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\leaf{o o o m}{
  node[leaf]{
    6\nodepart{two}8\nodepart{three}2\nodepart{four}#4
  }
}


\tikzset{
  btree/.style={
    nodes={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal=true,draw},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=\textwidth/4},
    leaf/.style={rectangle split allocate boxes=4}
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[btree]
\node (root) {test}
  child {\leaf{5}}
  child {\leaf[a]{5}}
  child {\leaf[a][b]{5}}
  child {\leaf[a][b][c]{5}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Adding `leaf/.style={..., rectangle split part fill=white}` seems to fix the symptoms though not the root cause - any possibile solution to use this with transparent nodes?

Comment: really best to avoid g

Comment: Don't use `g`: it's deprecated and it's bad practice. Apparently commands there need to be expandable, so you can use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\leafOptional{o m}{node[leaf]{#2 \IfValueT{#1}{\nodepart{two} #1}}}` and then use `\leafOptional{5}` or `\leafOptional[opt]{5}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik okay it just seemed convenient to use only curly bracket. I tried using `o m` and it worked for one and two part nodes though `o o m` and more optional arguments seemed to lead to tikz not correctly recognizing the resulting box in drawing the edge into the center of the node overlaying it.

Comment: Using macros in TikZ paths isn't that straight-forward. They need to be fully expandable. What is your preferred Input-Syntax and what should it do?

Answer (score 0):

I find using `node[leaf] {\leaf ...}` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes.multipart}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\leaf{o o o m}{
    6\nodepart{two}8\nodepart{three}2\nodepart{four}#4
}

\tikzset{
  btree/.style={
    nodes={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal=true,draw},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=\textwidth/4},
    leaf/.style={rectangle split allocate boxes=4}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[btree]
  \node (root) {test}
    child { node[leaf]{\leaf{5}} }
    child { node[leaf]{\leaf[a]{5}} }
    child { node[leaf]{\leaf[a][b]{5}} }
    child { node[leaf]{\leaf[a][b][c]{5}} }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that is also what my second code snippet does though I want to _avoid filling the leafs_ as my plan is to superimpose this over another graphic/background

Comment: @Septatrix I guess it is the not-fully-expandable command `\nodepart` that causes the original problem.

Comment: It do not think so. All four rows calling my `\leaf` macro should expand to the same thing (a node with four parts) and the first two rows work as expected and only the later two do not. My guess it that it has to do with the additional optional arguments passed to the macro...